# pip install numpy not installing file

Tags: python, numpy, ssl, pip, conda

On command, pip install numpy this error is coming

```
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certifica
te verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certifica
te verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certifica
te verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certifica
te verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certifica
te verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sim
ple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Answer (score 1):

You should update your pip as suggested in the error message. This will cure your problem if it is related to a possibly obsoleted TLS version.

Answer (score 0):

Open anaconda nevigator and try to upgrade jupyternotebook and nevigator from inside the notebook otherwise you should go for reinstalling that actually I am having also this problem. I search a lot on internet but atlast I uninstall and reinstall it and than download all the libraries now its working good.

[see this image on clicking on circled area you can upgrade this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKfIt.png)